# Ubuntu 22.04 can't connect to monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, xubuntu, multiple-monitors

I do not know how to debug this error, but I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 as a dual boot with windows 11. Windows 11 can see my monitor just fine. My ubuntu OS does not connect.

I have tried running both xorg and wayland by changing the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf but other than that I do not know how to debug it.

As far as system specs:
Hardware model: Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 3
Processor: Intel Core i7-01750H
Graphics: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
Gnome version 42.1

Comment: Please clarify your OS, question details & tags.  You mention Kubuntu & Xubuntu which doesn't use `gdm3` thus changes to gdm3 config will make no difference. Those OSes also don't use GNOME so what are you running?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 22.04 for desktop, I'm not sure what tag that is supposed to have?

Comment: Re: tags if you're using vanilla Ubuntu then certainly tags as "kubuntu" or "Xubuntu" are incorrect. Likewise if you have the graphics mentioned and not Nvidia, tagging as "Nividia" is incorrect.

Comment: I do have Nvidia. I've fixed the ubuntu tags - previously when I typed in Ubuntu, Ubuntu tag did not pop up so I assumed I couldn't choose it. I didn't realize you could just press the space bar and it would become a tag